# Typescript: Enforce union operation for the inputs from the result type (calculate backwards)

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to find a type-safe way to write the following function:

```
const merge = <A, B, C>(a: A, b: B): C => ({...a, ...b});
```

*Obviously, this does not compile, nor do I expect it to, it's just to show that the function should return the union of the 2 inputs, where `b` takes precedence over `a` in case of overlap.*

I found [an article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/05/14/type-safe-object-merging-2-8/) that describes a type-safe way to merge 2 objects. In short this is a modified version of the article:

```
type Omit<T, U> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>>;
type Defined<T> = T extends undefined ? never : T;
type MergedProperties<T, U> = {
    [K in (keyof T & keyof U)]:
    undefined extends T[K]
        ? Defined</* T[K] | */ U[K]>
        : T[K]
};

const merge = <T extends object, U extends object>(t: T, u: U) => ({
    ...t,
    ...u
} as Omit<T, U> & Omit<U, T> & MergedProperties<U, T>);
```

Which means, the code compiles if used right, meaning the 2 input types are of type `A` and `B`, and the output is of type `C` in the following code snippet:

```
type A = { a: string; b: number };
type B = { /* no a */ b: string, c: number };

type C = { a: string, b: string, c: number };
```

So given `a`, `b` and `c` whose respective types are their capitalized type, I can write this:

```
const c: C = merge(a, b);
```

### The Problem

If I change either the type `B` or the type `C` (e.g: adding a new property), the compiler will complain that `C` (the assignment) does not satisfy the given condition. **What I want, is the compiler to complain, that the inputs are wrong.**

Okay, so I define my output type early on and expect the function to adjust accordingly, in this form:

```
const merge = <C>() => <A, B>(a: A, b: B): C => ({...a, ...b});
```

Now I need to adjust `A` and `B`, to say that `A` and `B` give out `C`. I imagine this would work:

```
type Omit<T, U> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>>;
const merge = <C>() => <A extends Omit<C, B>, B extends Omit<C, A>>(
    a: A, b: B
): C => ({ ...a, ...b});
```

Meaning: If I exclude every key from `A` that is defined in `B` and every key from `B` that is defined in `A`, but individually they extend `C`, together they give out type `C` - with union types in case of overlaps - (or I get endless recursion (?)).

It says `TS2322: Type 'A & B' is not assignable to type 'C'.` Only so much.

If I change `A` to `A extends C`, it will work.

If I change `A` to `A extends Omit<C, never>`, it doesn't and I do not understand why. (It should be type `C` from which I excluded nothing.)

So how can I define the types `A` and `B` so that both of them together give out `C` (the generics in the parameterless function input) so that when I change either input in the returned function, the compiler complains at the input parameters, and not the output parameters?

Comment: Does it work for you if you change your second `merge` to `<C>() => <A extends Omit<C, B>, B extends Omit<C, A>>(a: A, b: B) => ({ ...a, ...b}) as unknown as C`?  That is, use a type assertion?  You're already doing that with the original `merge()` which returns `({ ...t, ...u}) as Omit<T, U> & Omit<U, T> & MergedProperties<U, T>)`.  Or do you need something else?

Comment: I'm also a bit unclear about your use cases.  Do you want `merge<C>()({ a: false }, { a: false, b: "", c: 0 })` to throw an error or be accepted?

Comment: I am a bit confused, because it does work what you have just written, but I don't understand it exactly. I thought type assertion should be used **1)**: if the return type is `any` in lambda functions or **2)**: the compiler cannot guess the return type and `as` forces the value to be cast. Why can't the type system guess it on it's own, why is 'hacking' needed? Isn't `as unknown as C` a hack? (I could as well write `as any as C`.) What is more, why does it behave differently for `A extends C` as opposed to `A extends Omit<C, never>`, although they are technically the same?

Comment: It would be end goal, yes if it would throw an error, but I first wanted to create a basic setup. Btw sry for the many questions, it's just very difficult to understand these advanced types.

Comment: The type system can't figure it out either because it requires human-level intelligence or because it wouldn't be worth it for the compiler to try to make such guesses all the time (lots of performance penalty for only occasional benefit).  You might want to think about how you'd program a compiler to figure this out.  
Assertions are the right way to go here; I think calling it a "hack" is a matter of opinion.  Certainly they were introduced to the language for use cases exactly like this.

Comment: Fair enough with the circular reference, but why doesn't the expression only by itself`A extends Omit<B, never>` evaluate to `A extends B`? Typescript understands it somehow internally, it just doesn't seem to finish the last step and resolve the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd proceed with your stated requirements.

First, make a type that represents the output of merging two types, so we can refer to it easily later:

```
type Merged<T extends object, U extends object> =
  Omit<T, U> & Omit<U, T> & MergedProperties<U, T>;
```

Now let's defined your curried `merge()` function.  I'm going to call it `mergeConstrained()`:

```
const mergeConstrained: <C>() =>
  <A extends object, B extends object>(
    a: A,
    b: B & (Merged<A, B> extends C ? B : C)
  ) => Merged<A, B>
  = () => (a, b) => ({ ...a, ...b }) as any;
```

Note the type of `b` is `B & (Merged<A, B> extends C ? B : C)`.  The presence of `B & ...` causes the compiler to infer `B` to be the type of the passed-in `b` parameter, just as it would if the type of `b` were simply `B`.  Once it makes this inference, it evaluates the intersection.  The second constituent of the intersection is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) which checks to see if `Merged<A, B>` is assignable to `C`.  If so, then `b` is acceptable, and the intersection becomes `B & B` or just `B`.  No errors will be output  in such cases.  If, however, `Merged<A, B>` is *not* assignable to `C`, then you've passed in a bad `b` parameter... and the intersection becomes `B & C`.  In such cases, the `b` parameter is not going to be assignable to `C`, and you'll get an error about where it goes wrong.

And the return type is `Merged<A, B>` instead of `C`, so you don't lose any type information about any extra properties passed in.  Actually, since you probably would rather not look at output types like `Merged<{a: string, d: boolean}, {b: string, c: number}>`, and would prefer `{a: string, b: string, c: number, d: boolan}`, there's a more complicated version of `mergeConstrained()` which will do that for you:

```
const mergeConstrained: <C>() =>
  <A extends object, B extends object, CC=Merged<A, B>>(
    a: A,
    b: B & ([CC] extends [C] ? B : C)
  ) => { [K in keyof CC]: CC[K] }
  = () => (a, b) => ({ ...a, ...b }) as any;
```

This ends up storing the result of `Merged<A, B>` in a type parameter `CC` and returning a mapped type to pull it apart.  Users will be happier with this version, even though it's uglier for the implementer.

Oh and yes, the implementation of `mergeConstrained()` is using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) because there's little chance that the compiler could understand such type manipulation of generic types.

Let's see if this works as you want:

```
type C = { a: string, b: string, c: number };

const mergeC = mergeConstrained<C>();

// normal use
const okay = mergeC({ a: "" }, { b: "", c: 0 }); // okay

// wrong property types
const wrongProps = mergeC({}, { a: "a", b: "b", c: "c" }); // error!
// string is not assignable to number --------> ~

// missing properties give an error
const missingProps = mergeC({ a: "" }, { b: "" }); // error!
// missing "a" and "c" --------------> ~~~~~~~~~
// error could be better but at least it warns about "c"

// extra properties are accepted
const extraProp = mergeC({ a: "" }, { b: "", c: 1, d: 3 });
// extraProp is type { a: string; b: string; c: number; d: number; }

// overlapping props are accepted
const overlap = mergeC({ a: "", b: "" }, { b: "", c: 1 }); //okay

// overlapping props where the merged type is okay are accepted
const overlapBadFirst = mergeC({ a: "", b: 123 }, { b: "", c: 1 }); //okay

// overlapping props where the merged type is wrong are an error
const overlapBadSecond = mergeC({ a: "", b: "" }, { b: 123, c: 1 }); //okay
// number is not assignable to string ------------> ~
```

That behavior looks reasonable to me.  Here's a [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=type%20Omit%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20keyof%20U%3E%3E%3B%0Atype%20Defined%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20undefined%20%3F%20never%20%3A%20T%3B%0Atype%20MergedProperties%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%5BK%20in%20%28keyof%20T%20%26%20keyof%20U%29%5D%3A%0A%20%20undefined%20extends%20T%5BK%5D%0A%20%20%3F%20Defined%3C%2F%2A%20T%5BK%5D%20%7C%20%2A%2F%20U%5BK%5D%3E%0A%20%20%3A%20T%5BK%5D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atype%20Merged%3CT%20extends%20object%2C%20U%20extends%20object%3E%20%3D%0A%20%20Omit%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%26%20Omit%3CU%2C%20T%3E%20%26%20MergedProperties%3CU%2C%20T%3E%3B%0A%0Aconst%20mergeConstrained%3A%20%3CC%3E%28%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%3CA%20extends%20object%2C%20B%20extends%20object%2C%20CC%3DMerged%3CA%2C%20B%3E%3E%28%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20A%2C%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20B%20%26%20%28%5BCC%5D%20extends%20%5BC%5D%20%3F%20B%20%3A%20C%29%0A%20%20%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20CC%5D%3A%20CC%5BK%5D%20%7D%0A%20%20%3D%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20%28a%2C%20b%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%20...a%2C%20...b%20%7D%29%20as%20any%3B%0A%0Atype%20C%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20string%2C%20c%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20mergeC%20%3D%20mergeConstrained%3CC%3E%28%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20normal%20use%0Aconst%20okay%20%3D%20mergeC%28%7B%20a%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20b%3A%20%22%22%2C%20c%3A%200%20%7D%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20okay%0A%0A%2F%2F%20wrong%20property%20types%0Aconst%20wrongProps%20%3D%20mergeC%28%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%20%22a%22%2C%20b%3A%20%22b%22%2C%20c%3A%20%22c%22%20%7D%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%21%0A%2F%2F%20string%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20number%20--------%3E%20~%0A%0A%2F%2F%20missing%20properties%20give%20an%20error%0Aconst%20missingProps%20%3D%20mergeC%28%7B%20a%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20b%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%21%0A%2F%2F%20missing%20%22a%22%20and%20%22c%22%20--------------%3E%20~~~~~~~~~%0A%2F%2F%20error%20could%20be%20better%20but%20at%20least%20it%20warns%20about%20%22c%22%0A%0A%2F%2F%20extra%20properties%20are%20accepted%0Aconst%20extraProp%20%3D%20mergeC%28%7B%20a%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20b%3A%20%22%22%2C%20c%3A%201%2C%20d%3A%203%20%7D%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%20extraProp%20is%20type%20%7B%20a%3A%20string%3B%20b%3A%20string%3B%20c%3A%20number%3B%20d%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20overlapping%20props%20are%20accepted%0Aconst%20overlap%20%3D%20mergeC%28%7B%20a%3A%20%22%22%2C%20b%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20b%3A%20%22%22%2C%20c%3A%201%20%7D%29%3B%20%2F%2Fokay%0A%0A%2F%2F%20overlapping%20props%20where%20the%20merged%20type%20is%20okay%20are%20accepted%0Aconst%20overlapBadFirst%20%3D%20mergeC%28%7B%20a%3A%20%22%22%2C%20b%3A%20123%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20b%3A%20%22%22%2C%20c%3A%201%20%7D%29%3B%20%2F%2Fokay%0A%0A%2F%2F%20overlapping%20props%20where%20the%20merged%20type%20is%20wrong%20are%20an%20error%0Aconst%20overlapBadSecond%20%3D%20mergeC%28%7B%20a%3A%20%22%22%2C%20b%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20b%3A%20123%2C%20c%3A%201%20%7D%29%3B%20%2F%2Fokay%0A%2F%2F%20number%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20string%20------------%3E%20~) to the code above.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this shows a really great technique with the extra derived generic type. I only have one question: What is this called and what is this doing: `[CC] extends [C]`? Why not just `CC extends C`? Btw: I really appreciate your two examples, though interestingly, the first one is getting evaluated to 'simpler' types in IntelliJ, but not the second one. (It's just a remark, it doesn't matter now.)

Comment: I'm doing `[CC] extends [C]` to prevent the conditional type from being [distributed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types).  It only makes a difference when `CC` is a union type.

Comment: Thanks for writing helping me